# Help with computing convolution of gaussian and dirac delta

Tags: normal-distribution, convolution, integral, rating

I'm trying to calculate message passing in Trueskill factor, [Trueskill paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2006/file/f44ee263952e65b3610b8ba51229d1f9-Paper.pdf). Given only two players competing, the message from difference factor to winner team node t1 would be
$$
\begin{align}
m_{f_d \rightarrow t_1} &= \int \int m_{d \rightarrow f_d} 
\cdot m_{t_2 \rightarrow f_d} \cdot f_d d t_2 d \text{d} \\
&= \int \int \mathbb{I}(d > \epsilon) \cdot N(t_2 ; s_2, \sigma_2^2 + \beta^2) \cdot 
\mathbb{I}(d = t_1 - t_2) d t_2 d \text{d} \\
\end{align}
$$

and the message from difference factor to difference node d is

\begin{align}
m_{f_d \rightarrow d} & = \int m_{t_1 \rightarrow f_d} \cdot m_{t_2 \rightarrow f_d}
 \cdot f_d dt_1 dt_2  \\
& = \int \int N(t_1 ; \mu_1, \sigma_1^2 + \beta^2) \cdot N(t_2 ; \mu_2, \sigma_2^2 + \beta^2) \cdot
\delta(d - t_1 + t_2) d t_1 d t_2 \\
\end{align}

The first one would be cdf of gaussian, and the second one would be a gaussian with changed mean and variance. How can I derive the full derivation of equations?

Comment: The meaning of your symbols is (extremely) obscure.  (I don't even see a Dirac delta in the integrand.  The apparent indicator $\mathbb{I}(d=t_1-t_2)$ is *not* a Dirac delta.) However, the result of any "convolution ... dirac delta" is part of the *definition* of $\delta.$  See the two definitions (following the "heuristic," which is a bad one) in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions).  Because this is a matter of definition, it is difficult to see what kind of derivation might be needed.

Comment: Re your flag: the "apply the definition" part of my comment remains relevant.